# Can't access local php website (Linux)

Tags: php, server

I have a computer with a PHP server hosted at 192.168.0.5:8080 and I just can't get access to it from another computer in the same network. This is the command I use on the directory where the site is:

`php --server localhost:8080`

Comment: If you want the site to be accessible you need to bind it to the *external* IP address, 192.168.0.5, *not* "localhost". Then you can verify with `netstat -na | grep 8080` whether there is a LISTENing port at 192.168.0.5:8080. If it still doesn't work, check out the firewall settings (note that `php --server` is only intended for debugging use).

Comment: What should I use when not debugging?

Comment: My personal preference goes to Apache `httpd`, but others could recommend `nginx` (much depends on your OS though). If you're just beginning, there are also self-contained virtual machine setups, and also "stacks". Linux, Apache, MySQL and PHP collectively form what's popularly known as the LAMP stack (WAMP for Windows); you might want to look into an already-made package for your operating system.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try `php --server 0.0.0.0:8080` - your example only binds to localhost